# What's the consistency strength of this extension of ML.

Tags: first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

$small (x) \equiv_{df} \\\exists y \subset WF \cup N ([y \in V \lor |y|<|WF \cup N|] \land |x| \leq |y|)$

Where $|x| \leq |y| \equiv_{df} \exists f (f:x \rightarrowtail y)$, and $|x| < |y| \equiv_{df} |x| \leq |y| \ \land |y| \not\leq |x|$

Where $\rightarrowtail$ denotes *"injections"*, $V$ is the set of all sets (i.e. elements of classes), $WF$ is the class of all well founded sets, and $N$ is the set of all Frege's naturals. Where a Frege natural is a set that is an equivalence class of finite sets under equivalence relation "set-bijection"

Now "[ML](https://books.google.iq/books?id=wf3iBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=Quine%27s%20revised%20edition%20of%20ML&source=bl&ots=H35QNBpYtX&sig=ACfU3U11TIrPGcskjFHLKNjjH5vX9mkbew&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifiZCOh4XoAhXMKewKHRI4DVYQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=Quine%27s%20revised%20edition%20of%20ML&f=false) + every hereditarily small class is a set", does prove all rules of ZF+Global choice over WF, and ZFC - foundation over the hereditarily small sets realm.

> Question 1: What's the consistency strength of this theory?
>
> Question 2: Can this theory prove global choice over the realm of hereditarily small sets?

Comment: I assume ML here is Rosser's extension of Quine's NF to allow proper classes.  Kindly share what "Frege's naturals" means in this context?

Comment: @hardmath, yes it is Rosser's extension, which is included in the revised version of Quine's ML. adopting Wang's correction. Thanks for the notes, I've added them.